# tcshでset var =` cat sjis.txt`を実行するとMissing}.が出力される

Tags: linux, shell

tcshで`` set var =`cat sjis.txt` ``を実行すると`Missing}.`が出力されてしまいます

tcsh-6.14では正常に実行できていましたが、tcsh-6.18では上記のエラーが発生します

・手順

1. SJISのテキストファイル「SJIS.txt」を作成する
2. 「SJIS.txt」に本と記載し、保存する。
3. 「test.csh」を作成し、以下を記載する。

   ```
   $ #!/bin/tcsh -f
   $ set var = `cat SJIS.txt`
   ```
4. 以下のコマンドを実行する

   ```
   $ ./test.csh
   ```

Answer (score 5):

`set var=`の左辺をダブルクオートでくくることで解消すると思います。

```
    例
    set var="`cat SJIS.txt`"
```

＃SJIS.txtの内容依存の挙動と思います。具体的には、バイトデータ中に"}"が含まれている
  と予想します。(あるいはロケールがShift_JISでない何か)

Comment: ダブルクオートで括ることで、setすることができました！varをechoする場合も、同様に括ることで文字化けせずに日本語が表示できています。大変助かりました。ありがとうございます。